# Exibir PDF em um Dialog

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, ireport, pdf

Estou querendo mudar a forma que o usuário visualiza o relatório do sistema que estou desenvolvendo, atualmente ao clicar no botão para ver o relatório, é dada a opção para o usuário fazer o download ou abrir direto no visualizador de PDF que estiver instalado na máquina, porém já vi em muitos sistemas web, no qual exibe uma tela idêntica ao visualizador de pdf, onde permite o mesmo já ver o relatório, sem download propriamente dito e imprimir facilitando assim a vida dele. Já tentei de varias forma a a ultima tentativa o código ficou assim:

ExecutorRelatorio

```
public class ExecutorRelatorio implements Work {

    private String caminhoRelatorio;
    private Map<String, Object> parametros;
    private String nomeArquivoSaida;
    InputStream arquivo; 

    public ExecutorRelatorio(String caminhoRelatorio, Map<String, Object> parametros, String nomeArquivoSaida) {
        this.caminhoRelatorio = caminhoRelatorio;
        this.parametros = parametros;
        this.nomeArquivoSaida = nomeArquivoSaida;

        this.parametros.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, new Locale("pt", "BR"));
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try {
            JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager
                    .compileReport(getClass().getResourceAsStream(this.caminhoRelatorio));

            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parametros, connection);
            byte[] b = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);

            arquivo = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
            arquivo.read();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new SQLException("Erro ao executar relatório " + this.caminhoRelatorio, e);
        }
    }

    public InputStream getArquivo() {
        return arquivo;
    }

    public String getNomeArquivoSaida() {
        return nomeArquivoSaida;
    }

}
```

RelatorioFichaEmergenciaBean

```
@Named
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class RelatorioFichaEmergenciaBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long registro;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    @Inject
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{pdfMB}")
    private PdfMB pdfMB;

    public void emitir(ActionEvent event) {

        UIParameter parameter = (UIParameter) event.getComponent().findComponent("registroId");
        registro = Long.parseLong(parameter.getValue().toString());

        Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("registro", registro);

        ExecutorRelatorio executor = new ExecutorRelatorio("/relatorios/ficha_emergencia.jrxml", parametros,
                "Ficha de Emergência.pdf");

        pdfMB.gerar(executor.getArquivo(), executor.getNomeArquivoSaida());

        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(executor);
}

    public PdfMB getPdfMB() {
        return pdfMB;
    }

    public void setPdfMB(PdfMB pdfMB) {
        this.pdfMB = pdfMB;
    }

}
```

PdfMB

```
/**
 * 
 * @author Weverton Reis
 * Fórum: GUJ
 *
 */

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PdfMB implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private StreamedContent pdf;

    /**
     * Esse método deixa o arquivo pronto para ser exibido na tela.
     * 
     * @param arquivo O arquivo pronto para ser apresentado.
     * @param nomeArquivo Nome do arquivo.
     */
    public void gerar(InputStream arquivo, String nomeArquivo) {
         pdf = new DefaultStreamedContent(arquivo, "application/pdf", nomeArquivo);
    }

    public StreamedContent getPdf() {
        try {
            if(pdf != null){
                 pdf.getStream().reset();
            }        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pdf;
    }

    public void setPdf(StreamedContent pdf) {
        this.pdf = pdf;
   }

}
```

Pagina xHTML

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
     xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">

    <p:toolbar style="margin-top: 20px">
        <p:toolbarGroup>
            <p:button value="Novo" icon="ui-icon-circle-plus"
                outcome="/atendimento/Atendimento" />
            <p:commandButton value="Salvar" icon="ui-icon-disk" update="@form"
                action="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.salvar}" />
            <p:button value="Pesquisar" icon="ui-icon-circle-zoomin"
                outcome="/atendimento/PesquisaAtendimento" />
            <p:commandButton value="Imprimir Fichas" icon="ui-icon-print"
                oncomplete="PF('fichasPaciente').show()" process="@this"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.cancelado}">
            </p:commandButton>
            <p:commandButton value="Imprimir Laudo de AIH" update="@form"
                icon="ui-icon-print"
                 disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.naoInternado}"
                actionListener="#{relatorioLaudoAih.emitir}" ajax="false">
                 <f:param id="registroIdLaudo" name="registroId"
                    value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.registro}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        </p:toolbarGroup>

         <p:toolbarGroup align="right">
            <p:commandButton value="Realizar Atendimento"
                action="#{atenderAtendimentoBean.mudarParaEmAtendimento}"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.naoAguardandoAtendimento}"
                process="@form" update="@form" />
            <p:commandButton value="Observação" icon="ui-icon-check"
                action="#{observacaoAtendimentoBean.mudarParaObservacao}"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.aguardandoAtendimento}"
                process="@form" update="@form" />
            <p:commandButton value="Internamento" icon="ui-icon-locked"
                oncomplete="PF('subTelaInternamento').show()"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.aguardandoAtendimento}"
                process="@this" />
            <p:button value="Alta" outcome="/saida/Saida" icon="ui-icon-home"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.aguardandoAtendimento}">
                <f:param id="saida" name="atendimento"
                    value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.registro}" />
            </p:button>
            <p:button value="Transferir" icon="ui-icon-alert"
                outcome="/transferencia/Transferencia"
                disabled="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.aguardandoAtendimento}">
                <f:param id="transferencia" name="atendimento"
                    value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.registro}" />
            </p:button>

            <p:separator />

            <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" icon="ui-icon-cancel"
                process="@form" update="@form"
                action="#{cancelarAtendimentoBean.mudarParaCancelado}" />

         </p:toolbarGroup>
     </p:toolbar>

    <p:dialog header="Fichas do Paciente" widgetVar="fichasPaciente"
        id="fichasPaciente" modal="true" draggable="false" resizable="false">
        <p:commandButton value="Ficha de Atendimento" icon="ui-icon-print"
            actionListener="#{relatorioFichaEmergenciaBean.emitir}"
            update="@form, pgRelatorio" oncomplete="PF('viewRelatorio').show()">
            <f:param id="registroId" name="registroId"
                value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.registro}" />
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="Ficha do Paciente" icon="ui-icon-print"
            actionListener="#{relatorioFichaEmissaoAih.emitir}" update="@form"
            ajax="false">
            <f:param id="registroIdFicha" name="registroId"
                value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.registro}" />
        </p:commandButton>
    </p:dialog>

     <p:dialog header="Tela de Internamento" widgetVar="subTelaInternamento"
         id="subTelaInternamento" modal="true" draggable="false"
        resizable="false" closable="true">
         <p:panelGrid columns="2" style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px"
            columnClasses="rotulo, campo, rotulo, campo">

            <p:outputLabel value="Tipo da Clínica" for="tipoClinica" />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoClinica"
                value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.clinica}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione ..." itemDisabled="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{cadastroTipoClinicaBean.listaClinicas}"
                    var="clinica" itemValue="#{clinica}"
                    itemLabel="#{clinica.descricao}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

              <p:outputLabel value="Tipo do Internamento" for="tipoInternamento" />
              <p:selectOneMenu id="tipoInternamento"
                 value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.tipoAtendimento}"> 
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Selecione ..." itemDisabled="true" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Urgência/Emergência" itemValue="02" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Eletivo" itemValue="01" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <p:outputLabel value="Médico Responsável pelo internamento:"
                for="medicoResponsavelExec" />
             <p:autoComplete id="medicoResponsavelExec" size="40" dropdown="true"
                value="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.atendimento.profissionalMedicoExecutor}"
                  completeMethod="#{cadastroAtendimentoBean.completarProfissional}"
                  var="profissional" itemLabel="#{profissional.nome}"
                  itemValue="#{profissional}" forceSelection="true" />

        </p:panelGrid>

         <p:commandButton value="Internar Paciente"
            action="#{internamentoAtendimentoBean.mudarParaInternamento}"
            process="@form" update="@form"
             onclick="PF('subTelaInternamento').close();" />

     </p:dialog>

    <p:dialog header="Teste" widgetVar="viewRelatorio" width="900px"
        height="100%" id="viewRelatorio">
        <h:panelGrid id="pgRelatorio" columns="1"
            style="width: 100%; margin-top: 20px">
            <pe:documentViewer id="view" style="width:100%; height:100%;"
                value="#{pdfMB.pdf}" />
         </h:panelGrid>
    </p:dialog>
</ui:composition>
```

Dessa forma que está, não aparece erro algum no console, o dialogo é exibido porem o PDF do relatorio não aparece, fica apenas o componente vazio. Existe alguma coisa errada isso eu sei, porém não consegui identificar onde estou errando.

Comment: Esse projeto utiliza JSF com CDI, será esse o problema.